# Silverlight determine height of a textbox

Tags: textbox, height, silverlight-3.0

I have a scrollview control that has a `StackPanel` (Orientation=Vertical) UI Element inside of it.  I have a series of textboxes (24) inside the `StackPanel`.  The scrollviewer height = 250px.  Ideally, what I want is when I start to tab from textbox to the next textbox, I want the scrollview to automatically scrolldown without user interaction.

I have code that successfully does this.  How would I go about computing what the `TextBox` `Height` is?

My code looks something like:

```
private void TB_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (sender is TextBox)  
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        // but using tb.Height does not obtain the value for me.  It returns a NaN  
    }  
}
```

Any suggestions or comments otherwise would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `TextBox.ActualHeight` to get the height. The `Height` property is an indication of the height the `TextBox` desires, not the actual height.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ActualHeight` property.  That will give you what you want.